# Terraform: De-duping a map object

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm creating a map object by looping through a list of elements. How do I enforce unique keys in the map such that there are no duplicates?

For example, I have something like below but I get the error: `│ Local value local.uri_bucket_map cannot use its own result as part of its expression.`

```
locals {
  inference = [
    { "data_uri" : "s3://my_bucket/model.tar.gz", 
      "model_uri": "account_num.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my_container:latest"
    },
    { "data_uri" : "s3://my_bucket/model.tar.gz",
      "model_uri": "account_num.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my_container2:latest"
    },
    { "data_uri" : "s3://my_bucket_3/model.tar.gz" ,
      "model_uri": "account_num.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my_container3:latest"
    }
  ]

  uri_bucket_map = {
    for x in local.inference : x.data_uri =>
    split("/", split("//", x.data_uri)[1])[0]
  }
}
```

Expected Map:

```
{
"s3://my_bucket/model.tar.gz" -> "my_bucket"
"s3://my_bucket_3/model.tar.gz" -> "my_bucket_3"
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Its unclear what do you mean by "duplicates" duplicates in what? Data_uri, model_uri, both?

Comment: Duplicates in the `uri_bucket_map`. So right now, it will fail because s3://my_bucket_model.tar.gz will appear twice in the map keys, so how do we skip this when the key already exists in the map

Comment: Please update the question with the expected result map without duplicates.

Comment: Updated with expected result map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much changes to you original code, you can obtain what you want as follows:

```
  uri_bucket_map = {
    for x in distinct(local.inference[*].data_uri) : x =>
        split("/", split("//", x)[1])[0]
  }
```